# Is there a way to download Remix IDE locally and access it from the Terminal (Linux)?

Tags: remix, compiler, linux

Is there a way to download Remix IDE locally and access it from the Terminal (Linux)?

Hi,

I think I have read that it should be possible to download Remix IDE and use it offline. In the latest release notes it also says that Remix should be accessible from the Terminal.

But I have not found more documentation on these subjects.

Anyone knows how to combine these two methods? Getting Remix to run offline and also being able to access it from a Terminal on Linux.

Vesa

Comment: checkout this [repo](https://github.com/ethereum/remix)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to utilize this project now (arguably) is to [pull from docker](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project#run-with-docker) as per the offical repo:

`docker pull remixproject/remix-ide:latest`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Document step by step. Also, you can download from github. while installation in ubuntu may be you face the problem of 'node-gyp rebuild'. so keep in this mind. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/remix-ide

Comment: Can I use it from NodeJS? Can I use it directly in the Linux Terminal? Also is there a manual file or something like that? I would prefer not using a browser as I'm using SSH only and I don't have a graphical environment.

Comment: yes,  Basically you can use solc compiler directly to run  in terminal. you can find some post on medium regarding direct run .sol file through ubuntu terminal.  Use browser help you to understand the whole running process. If you beginner then i recommend you to use graphical environment. Thanks.